# awk: Pipeline and "@" as delimiter

Tags: awk, solaris

I am trying to apply two delimiter using `awk` which are `|` and `@` at the same time using something like this:

```
awk -F"[@|]"  '{print NF}'
```

But the output is always taking only one of them as separator but not the other.

O.S: Solaris

Comment: Pretty sure the default awk on solaris will not allow a regular expression as the FS. But you should have newer awks installed, perhaps `/usr/xpg4/bin/nawk` (?? I don't have a solaris box handy)

Comment: possibly [/usr/xpg4/bin/awk](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5165/awk-1.html)

Comment: bash-3.2$ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk
Usage:  awk [-F ERE] [-v var=val] 'program' [var=val ...] [file ...]
        awk [-F ERE] -f progfile ... [-v var=val] [var=val ...] [file ...]

Comment: You may have your syntax wrong? For me using gawk version 4.1.4 the supplied field separators are an array, not a regex, so `echo "A|B@B|@@NJK|J|K|@|" | awk -F "[|,@]" '{print NF}'` returns 11 (notice the , <comma> separating the array elements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [awk provided by Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5165/awk-1.html) in `/usr/bin/awk` does not support a regular expression as an argument to `-F`:

> ```
>  /usr/bin/awk [-f progfile] [-Fc] [' prog '] [parameters]
>       [filename]...
> ```

...

> ```
>  -Fc            Uses the character c as the  field  separator
>                 (FS)  character.   See  the  discussion of FS
>                 below.
> ```

... while the one in `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` does:

> ```
>  /usr/xpg4/bin/awk [-FcERE] [-v assignment]... 'program' -f progfile...
>       [argument]...
> ```

Comment: It is misleading that later in the man page the Built-in variable `FS` is described as `input field separator regular expression ...` ... until you realize that `The /usr/xpg4/bin/awk utility is described on the nawk(1) manual page.`

Comment: ack; the words didn't make it from my brain to my fingers -- thanks, Stéphane!

Comment: Use `PATH=$(/usr/xpg4/bin/getconf PATH):$PATH` to get the XPG4 tools as the default ones (but you may also have XPG5 and later, see `man standards`).